# ld: framework not found url_launcher on Flutter, xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I started facing an issue of

> framework not found

, when upgraded flutter from 2.8.1 to 2.10.1.
I'm working on mac m1
I tried pub and pod clean with complete cache by using below command and also tried fresh setup on new system

```
flutter clean
pod cache clean 'FortifySec' --all
 rm -rf Pods
pod deintegrate
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ../pubspec.lock
rm -rf .symlinks
pod cache clean --all
flutter pub cache clean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on xcode 13.1, resolved my issue by just removing frameworks entry in build setting.

```
xcode -> target -> Build settings-> Other Linker flag
```

Removed all entry for thoes it was showing error.

[image]